# How can I constrain a value parsed with argparse (for example, restrict an integer to positive values)?

Tags: python, argparse

I have this code so far:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-g", "--games", type=int, default=162,
                    help="The number of games to simulate")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

It does not make sense to supply a negative value for the number of games, but `type=int` allows any integer. For example, if I run `python simulate_many.py -g -2`, `args.games` will be set to `-2` and the program will continue as if nothing is wrong.

I realize that I could just explicit check the value of `args.games` after parsing arguments. But **can I make `argparse` itself check this condition? How?**

I would prefer it to work that way so that the automatic usage message can explain the requirement to the user. Ideally, the output would look something like:

```
python simulate_many.py -g -2
usage: simulate_many.py [-h] [-g GAMES] [-d] [-l LEAGUE]
simulate_many.py: error: argument -g/--games: invalid positive int value: '-2'
```

just as it currently handles arguments that can't be converted to integer:

```
python simulate_many.py -g a
usage: simulate_many.py [-h] [-g GAMES] [-d] [-l LEAGUE]
simulate_many.py: error: argument -g/--games: invalid int value: 'a'
```

Answer (score 315, accepted):

This should be possible utilizing `type`. You'll still need to define an actual method that decides this for you:

```
def check_positive(value):
    ivalue = int(value)
    if ivalue <= 0:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("%s is an invalid positive int value" % value)
    return ivalue

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)
parser.add_argument('foo', type=check_positive)
```

This is basically just an adapted example from the `perfect_square` function in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html#type) on `argparse`.

Comment: Can your function have multiple values? How does that work?

Comment: If the conversion to `int` fails, will there still be a readable output? Or should you `try` `raise` the conversion manually for that?

Comment: @MrZ It'll give something like `error: argument foo: invalid check_positive value: 'foo=<whatever>'`. You'd could simply add a `try:` ... `except ValueError:` around it that re-raises an exception with a better error message.

Comment: You can wrap conversion in a `try-except` block. If exception is raised, then you can `raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(f"Expected integer, got {value}")`

Answer (score 88):

`type` would be the recommended option to handle conditions/checks, as in Yuushi's answer.

In your specific case, you can also use the `choices` parameter if your upper limit is also known:

```
parser.add_argument('foo', type=int, choices=xrange(5, 10))
```

**Note:** Use `range` instead of `xrange` for python 3.x

Comment: I imagine this would be fairly inefficient, as you would be generating a range and then cycling through it validate your input. A quick `if` is much faster.

Comment: @trav1th Indeed it might be, but it's an example usage from the docs. Also, I have said in my answer that Yuushi's answer is the one to go for. Good to give options. And in the case of argparse, it's happening once per execution, uses a generator (`xrange`) and doesn't require additional code. That trade-off is available. Up to each one to decide which way to go.

Comment: To be clearer about jgritty's point on ben author's answer, choices=xrange(0,1000) will result in the entire list of integers from 1 to 999 inclusive being written to your console every time you use --help or if an invalid argument is provided.  Not a good choice in most circumstances.

Comment: If you use a large range of numbers, I don't think this is the cleanest solution, as --help will output the integers that are processed, and completely screw the view of --help

Answer (score 15):

The quick and dirty way, if you have a predictable max as well as min for your arg, is use `choices` with a range

```
parser.add_argument('foo', type=int, choices=xrange(0, 1000))
```

Comment: The downside there is the hideous output.

Comment: emphasis on _dirty_, i guess.

Comment: To be clearer about jgritty's point, choices=xrange(0,1000) will result in the entire list of integers from 1 to 999 inclusive being written to your console every time you use --help or if an invalid argument is provided.  Not a good choice in most circumstances.

Answer (score 12):

In case someone (like me) comes across this question in a Google search, here is an example of how to use a modular approach to neatly solve the more general problem of allowing argparse integers *only in a specified range*:

```
# Custom argparse type representing a bounded int
class IntRange:

    def __init__(self, imin=None, imax=None):
        self.imin = imin
        self.imax = imax

    def __call__(self, arg):
        try:
            value = int(arg)
        except ValueError:
            raise self.exception()
        if (self.imin is not None and value < self.imin) or (self.imax is not None and value > self.imax):
            raise self.exception()
        return value

    def exception(self):
        if self.imin is not None and self.imax is not None:
            return argparse.ArgumentTypeError(f"Must be an integer in the range [{self.imin}, {self.imax}]")
        elif self.imin is not None:
            return argparse.ArgumentTypeError(f"Must be an integer >= {self.imin}")
        elif self.imax is not None:
            return argparse.ArgumentTypeError(f"Must be an integer <= {self.imax}")
        else:
            return argparse.ArgumentTypeError("Must be an integer")
```

This allows you to do something like:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)
parser.add_argument('foo', type=IntRange(1))     # Must have foo >= 1
parser.add_argument('bar', type=IntRange(1, 7))  # Must have 1 <= bar <= 7
```

The variable `foo` now allows only **positive integers**, like the OP asked.

Note that in addition to the above forms, just a maximum is also possible with `IntRange`:

```
parser.add_argument('other', type=IntRange(imax=10))  # Must have other <= 10
```

Answer (score 10):

Based on Yuushi's answer, you can also define a simple helper function that can check if a number is positive for various numeric types:

```
def positive(numeric_type):
    def require_positive(value):
        number = numeric_type(value)
        if number <= 0:
            raise ArgumentTypeError(f"Number {value} must be positive.")
        return number

    return require_positive
```

The helper function can be used to annotate any numeric argument type like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)
parser.add_argument("positive-integer", type=positive(int))
parser.add_argument("positive-float", type=positive(float))
```

Comment: `ArgumentTypeError` should be `argparse.ArgumentTypeError`.

Answer (score 8):

A simpler alternative, especially if subclassing `argparse.ArgumentParser`, is to initiate the validation from inside the `parse_args` method.

Inside such a subclass:

```
def parse_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
    """Parse and validate args."""
    namespace = super().parse_args(args, namespace)
    if namespace.games <= 0:
         raise self.error('The number of games must be a positive integer.')
    return namespace
```

This technique may not be as cool as a custom callable, but it does the job.

---

About [`ArgumentParser.error(message)`](https://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#exiting-methods):

> This method prints a usage message including the message to the standard error and terminates the program with a status code of 2.

---

Credit: [answer by jonatan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35083753/832230)

Comment: Or at the very least, replacing `print "-g/--games: must be positive."; sys.exit(1)` with just `parser.error("-g/--games: must be positive.")`. _(Usage like in [jonatan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35083753/1431750).)_

Answer (score 0):

Honor Yuushi's answer:

```
# helper
import argparse

def make_range_checker(lb, ub):
    flb, fub = float(lb), float(ub)
    def checker(val):
        val = int(val)
        if not (flb <= val <= fub):
            # error type must be correct
            # so argparse module catches the error
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(
                f'value out of scope: {lb} - {ub}')
        return val
    return checker

# usage
parser.add_argument("--sleep",
                    default=5,
                    type=make_range_checker(1, 'inf'),
                    help="sleep time in sec, must be postive int")
```