# Python argparse integer condition (>=12)

Tags: python, argparse

I need to request that an argument is >= 12 using `argparse`.

I cannot find a way to obtain this result using `argparse`, it seems there's no way to set rules to a given value but only full sets of accepted values like choices=['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'].

My code is:

```
import sys, argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-b", "--bandwidth", type=int, help="target bandwidth >=12")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.bandwidth and args.bandwidth < 12:
    print "ERROR: minimum bandwidth is 12"
    sys.exit(1)
```

I wonder if there is a way to obtain this result directly with some `argparse` option.

Comment: How about subclassing  `argparse.Action`, and override `__call__` to create `>=12` rule?

Comment: Can you write down a couple of lines of code?

Comment: Under 'related' is a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117415/using-argparse-allow-only-positive-integers thread.  The accepted answer there uses `type`, and points out that it is an adaptation of the documentation example, the one titled `perfect_square`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

One way is to use a custom type.

```
def bandwidth_type(x):
    x = int(x)
    if x < 12:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("Minimum bandwidth is 12")
    return x

parser.add_argument("-b", "--bandwidth", type=bandwidth_type, help="target bandwidth >= 12")
```

Note: I think `ArgumentTypeError` is a more correct exception to raise than `ArgumentError`. However, `ArgumentTypeError` is not documented as a public class by `argparse`, and so it may not be considered correct to use in your own code. One option I like is to use `argparse.error` like alecxe does in his answer, although I would use a custom action instead of a type function to gain access to the parser object.

A more flexible option is a custom action, which provides access to the current parser and namespace object.

```
class BandwidthAction(argparse.Action):

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if values < 12:
            parser.error("Minimum bandwidth for {0} is 12".format(option_string))
            #raise argparse.ArgumentError("Minimum bandwidth is 12")

        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

parser.add_argument("-b", "--bandwidth", action=BandwidthAction, type=int,
                     help="target bandwidth >= 12")
```

Comment: +1 custom action looks like a better option. Using `type` looks somewhat hacky.

Comment: I think it's valid to consider a range-restricted set of integers as a subtype of `int`, just like `N` (the natural numbers) is a subset of `Z` (the integers) in mathematics. The action is actually overkill, as there's no need to use, for example, the parser or the name of the option to type-check the value of the option.

Comment: I wanted to consider the case there's no upper limit and so the range is not a good option in my case.

Comment: `16.4.3.6. type` of the documentation has a custom `Type` example that raises a `argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)`.  `FileType` also raises an `ArgumentTypeError` if it can't open a file.  `ArgumentTypeError` is included in the `__all__` import.  The API documentation is not polished.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the correction. I made my comment based on the module docstring, which omits `ArgumentTypeError`. Clearly, I did not read down far enough, especially since `__all__` is only a few lines below the docstring.

Answer (score 27):

you can try with something you introduce in your explanation :

```
import sys, argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-b", "--bandwidth", type=int, choices=range(12,100))
args = parser.parse_args()
```

for example, thus , its Argparse which will raise the error itself with `invalid choice`

Comment: This introduces an artificial upper bound on the value.

Comment: its an example, we dont know the "upper" limit he needs

Comment: Why assume an upper limit exists at all?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to consider the case there's no upper limit

Comment: @chepner as i said it's an example which works with the keyword "choices" he introduced himself. but thx for the downvote for something that works, i'll keep it in mind. To giuspen ok so you find your solution ;)

Comment: It was not me to downvote even though in the question I mentioned that I was searching for something different from choices, I anyway thank you for spending time to write your opinion/solution :)

Comment: @giuspen yes i know that ;) but it's not important . thanks u 2

Comment: In theory `choices` works with anything that accepts the `in` operator (has a `__contains__`).  That would include something like `range(1, 65535)`.  But as discussed in http://bugs.python.org/issue16418 , the help and error messages can be problematic, since it tries to list all values.

Comment: This wouldn't work with a real number constrained to be inside an interval.

Comment: This will ruin the `-h, --help` message with printing all those choices

Comment: @Achilles nah, you just set `metavar='[1, 65535)'` or whatever, specify the `help` message and it won't print the list.

Comment: @Alnitak This only solves half of the issue. The help message is cleaned up, sure, but the error that gets raised when the value is out of the range can result in the outputting of a very large list that would obscure the terminal window.

Answer (score 27):

You can call the parser error without creating custom types or separate functions. A simple change to your code example is enough:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-b", "--bandwidth", type=int, help="target bandwidth >=12")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.bandwidth and args.bandwidth < 12:
    parser.error("Minimum bandwidth is 12")
```

This will cause the application to exit and display the parser error:

```
$ python test.py --bandwidth 11 
usage: test.py [-h] [-b BANDWIDTH]
test.py: error: Minimum bandwidth is 12
```

Comment: This does the job, and the technique can of course also be repurposed when subclassing `argparse.ArgumentParser`. For this, see the [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39947874/832230).

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
import sys, argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "-b", "--bandwidth", 
    type=lambda x: (int(x) > 11) and int(x) or sys.exit("Minimum bandwidth is 12"),
    help="target bandwidth >=12"
)
```

But plese note, I didn't try it in a real code. Or you can change `sys.exit` to `parser.error` as wrote by @jonatan.