# Parse command line argument using argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have utility which pass multiple argument alongwith require element Could anyone provide some input How can I handle this scenario using argparse. Please find the sample code

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-cdl", dest = "input_file")
args = parser.parse_args()
print args

Command Line :  python test_6.py -cdl sample (workfine)

utility also pass :  python test_6.py -cdl sample -cdl-sp -cdl-ck
```

The last two argument for tool.As my program I need to take sample file and ignore rest two argument without any error.In current code, it give me error

Comment: it should say "invalide choice: -cdl-sp" if you want to avoid this (which is not recommand) have a look at this one and may be you'll be able to test when an error occurs and fail silently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700634/python-argparse-integer-condition-12/18700996#18700996

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
args, rest = parser.parse_known_args()
print args
print rest
```

rest should equal

```
['-cdl-sp', '-cdl-ck']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add options for the arguments you don't need.

```
parser.add_argument("-cdl-sp", dest = "sp",  action='store_true')
parser.add_argument("-cdl-sk", dest = "sk",  action='store_true')
```

Comment: But it does not contain any value.  python test_6.py -cdl sample -cdl-sp -cdl-ck

Comment: With "action='store_true'" parser doesn't expect any value. You will get a boolean value true if argument is there, false if not.

Comment: it is also valid statement but above solution works better for me.As I write wrapper for call tool and some user can add more option and I need not to change any code But thanks for reply