# Parsing a list of IPs to argparse in python as string

Tags: python, string, argparse

I want to execute a python script that does something with several IP adresses. These adresses can be given via commad  line.

I use the following command for parsing:

```
parser.add_argument('--IP',dest='Adresses',help='some Ips', 
default=['192.168.2.15','192.168.2.3'],type=list,nargs='+')
```

However, when I run the script via command like the following:

```
python script.py --IP 192.168.2.15,192.168.2.3
```

It splits up the string after every character, the same behaviour occurs if I use a space instead of a comma, so if I print it out the following output happens

> [['1', '9', '2', '.', '1', '6', '8', '.', '2', '.', '1', '5'], ['1',
>   '9', '2', '.', '1', '6', '8', '.', '2', '.', '3']]

What I desire to have is:

> ['192.168.2.15','192.168.2.3']

like described in the default parameters

So two things I do not get to work here:

1. How can I parse several strings to argparse but under one argument, so that it gets seperated in a list
2. How can I stop the  splitting up by characters

Thank you for your help

Comment: You could just join them back back into strings... `["".join(x) for x in ip]`

Comment: Wouldn't this crash or change  when the parameters are not given and it must refer to the default parameters?

Comment: Hmm it works but I do not get why. Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is type `str` (the default) with just `nargs=+` and then presenting the addresses as real, separated arguments to the process.

so:

```
parser.add_argument('--IP', dest='Adresses', help='some Ips', 
                    default=['192.168.2.15','192.168.2.3'], nargs='+')
```

Will result in the following when called with two arguments:

```
parser.parse_args(['--IP', '123.45', '123.34'])
Namespace(Adresses=['123.45', '123.34'])
```

This would translate to the following command line call:

```
python script.py --IP 123.45 123.34
```

This is the intended way of using `nargs=+`, where the `type` parameter defines the element type of each list element.

In case you would really want to use the `IP1,IP2` format, you would need to  provide a custom checking function as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117415/in-python-using-argparse-allow-only-positive-integers), which would then need to manually split the input using string manipulation, including all the corner cases you have to handle then, which are automatically handled by `argparse` when using the proposed way.