# Processing command arguments in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add some arguments to my django command.
My command will be executing a sql query and I'd like
to have an optional argument --first_row and if --first_row
is specified the user must specify a second argment --last_row.

Here is what I have tried:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import time

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--first_row', type=int)
        parser.add_argument('--last_row', type=int)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        import argparse
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        self.add_arguments(parser)

        start = time.time()
        args = parser.parse_args()
        if args.first_row:
            print "first row is %d" % (args.first_row)
        end = time.time()
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS("Operation took %d seconds" % (end-start)))
```

But when I run my command I get this output:

```
manage.py > query_db --first_row 1 --last_row 5
usage: manage.py [-h] [--first_row FIRST_ROW] [--last_row LAST_ROW]
manage.py: error: unrecognized arguments: query_db

Process finished with exit code 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the path to your command? Like [Writing custom django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) example ?

Comment: Yes like Writing custom django-admin commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't instantiate a new `ArgumentParser` in your `handle` method. It doesn't know about the `query_db` argument, so you get the `unrecognized arguments: query_db` error.

There are some suggestions of how to handle mutually inclusive arguments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414060/argparse-required-argument-y-if-x-is-present). You could use the first suggestion and raise an error if `first_row` is present in `options` but `last_row` isn't:

```
from django.core.management import CommandError

def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('--first_row', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('--last_row', type=int)

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    if options['first_row'] is not None and options['last_row'] is None:
        raise CommandError("--last_row is required when --first_row is specified)
    ...
```

Comment: You could look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117415/in-python-using-argparse-allow-only-positive-integers) about only allowing positive integers with argparse. It might be simpler to add another if-statement in the `handle` method. There might be other checks you need to add, e.g. `first_row <= last_row`.