# TypeError: 'Namespace' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, scrapy, threadpool

When I run this script I want to add an argument in the console for the numbers of the consumers that I want to run together. For example `adsconsumer.py nb=10` would mean that I will run this script 10 times simultaneously.

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('nb=')
    nb = parser.parse_args()

    for i in range(nb):
        thread = Thread(target=process_consumer(), args=())
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: 'Namespace' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Can you please add the traceback? When do not know what `Namespace` is.

Comment: guess `nb` isn't an integer, but a string... Try forcing the `nb` to be positive integer, check this out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117415/in-python-using-argparse-allow-only-positive-integers

Comment: i didn't understand you can you explain more for me because i'm a beginner

Comment: @Aaron_ab can you help me with code please

Answer (score 1):

You are using nb as a numerical value so it should be. Try:

```
print(type(nb))
```

It should return str as the error indicates.

just convert it to integer as follows:

```
or i in range(int(nb)):
```

Or tell the agparser to treat the input as an integer:

```
def main():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('nb=',type=int)
nb = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: when i try type=int in the agparser i get this error

Comment: usage: selogerAdsconsumer.py [-h] nb=
selogerAdsconsumer.py: error: argument nb=: invalid int value: 'nb=10'

Comment: Is there a need for 'nb=' in your string? I believe you should remove it. does ab a variable that holds the integer value that you want to pass?

Comment: yeah i want to write in the console when i run the script the file name and the number of consumer like "selogerAdsconsumer.py nb=10"

Comment: SO the problem ould be in "range(nb)" as np will be holding a string and you are trying to interpret it as an integer.

Comment: What is the variable which holds the number of consumer?

Comment: nb holds the number of consumer

Comment: According to your code nb which is defined as "nb = parser.parse_args()
" this is a string, not an integer. There should be another var holds the number of consumers which you can add to the string 'nb=' using string formatting and use in the range as a numerical value without any errors.

Comment: okay , please can you help me with the code because i'm a beginner